# How exactly does alignment impact memory layout and the bahaviour of placement new?

Tags: c++, memory-alignment, placement-new, memory-layout, alignas

We read a lot about alignment and how important it is, for example for placement `new` usage, but I was wondering - how does it exactly alter the layout of the memory?

Obviously, if we do

```
char buffer[10];
std::cout << sizeof buffer;
```

and

```
alignas(int) char buffer[10];
std::cout << sizeof buffer;
```

we get the same result, which is `10`.

But the behaviour cannot be exactly the same, can it? How come it is distinguishable? I tried to seek the answer and ran to godbolt, testing the following code:

```
#include <memory>

int main() {
    alignas(int) char buffer[10];
    new (buffer) int;
}
```

which, under GCC 8.2 and no optimisations, results in following assembly:

```
operator new(unsigned long, void*):
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rsi
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    pop     rbp
    ret
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 16
    lea     rax, [rbp-12]
    mov     rsi, rax
    mov     edi, 4
    call    operator new(unsigned long, void*)
    mov     eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

Let's change the code slightly by removing the `alignas(int)` part. Now, the generated assembly is slightly different:

```
operator new(unsigned long, void*):
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rsi
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    pop     rbp
    ret
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 16
    lea     rax, [rbp-10]
    mov     rsi, rax
    mov     edi, 4
    call    operator new(unsigned long, void*)
    mov     eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

Notably, it differs only by `lea` instruction, where the second parameter is `[rbp-10]` instead of `[rbp-12]`, as we had in the `alignas(int)` version.

Please do note that I generally do not understand assembly. I cannot write assembly but I can somewhat read it. To my understanding, the difference simply alters the offset of a memory addres, which will hold our placement-`new`ed `int`.

But what does it achieve? Why do we need that? Suppose we have a 'generic' representation of the `buffer` array as follows:

```
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
```

Now, I would assume, that after placement-`new`ing the `int` (*with or without* the alignment), we would end up with something like this:

```
[x] [x] [x] [x] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
```

where `x` represents a single byte of an `int` (we assume that `sizeof(int) == 4`).

But I must be missing something. There is more to that and I do not know what. What exactly do we achieve by aligning the `buffer` to `int` suited alignment? What happens if we *don't* align it so?

Comment: The crux occurs when you placement new a `char` and then placement new an `int` immediately "after" it in the same buffer.

Comment: @MooingDuck so assuming that I will never mix the types which I placement-`new` into my buffer (*suppose* I mimick `std::vector`'s buffer in a very simplified way), I can just do that without any alignment?

Comment: no, alignment is still an issue, it's just hard to notice the problem until you mix types.

Comment: Related, but not quite answering this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member/119128#119128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some architectures, types must be aligned in order for operations to work correctly.  The address of `int`, for example, might need to be a multiple of 4.  If it isn't so aligned, then CPU instructions that operate on integers in memory wont work.

Even if everything *works* when data is not nicely aligned, alignment is still important for performance, because it ensures that integers, etc., don't cross cache boundaries.

When you align your `char` buffer to an integer boundary, it doesn't affect the way that placement new works.  It just ensures that you can use placement new to put an `int` at the start of your buffer without violating any alignment constraints.  It does this by ensuring that the address of the buffer is a multiple of 4 bytes.